# Use De Moivre's Theorem to express $\cos(4θ)$ in terms of sums and differences of powers of $\sin(θ)$ and $\cos(θ)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

So far I have gotten this far using the binomial theorem.

$(x + iy)^4 = x^4 + 4x^3y + 6i^2x^2y^2 + 4i^3xy^3 + i^4y^4$=
$x^4 - 6x^2y^2 + y^4 + i(4x^3y - 4xy^3)$

$i^2 = -1 $ let $x = cosθ$  and y = $sinθ$

$e^{i4θ} = cos4θ + isin4θ = (cosθ + i sinθ)^4 $

$cos4θ = cos^4θ - 6cos^2θsin^2θ + sin^4θ$

I am not quite sure where to go next from here? Have I expressed this correctly in terms of sinθ and cosθ?

Thanks for taking the time to review.

Comment: What is exactly you want to do?!

Comment: @Deliasaghi Express cos4x in terms of the powers of sinx and cosx. Not sure if I have done that at cos4x=cos4x−6cos2xsin2x+sin4x. I think I could possibly go further?

Comment: Plus or minus a few typos, yes this is OK. You could also replace $cos^2x$ with $1-sin^2x$ to give a representation just as powers of $sinx$. Similarly as powers of $cosx$.

Comment: @paul thanks very much. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct, but there are a few notational details. Firstly, a few misprints, for instance, $e^i40 = \cos 4x + i\sin x$ is probably meant to be $(e^i)^4 = \cos 4x + i\sin 4x$, or something like it.

Secondly, you're using the letter $x$ to do two diffferent things here. I would probably let the first line be $(a + ib)^4$ instead, and then insert $a = \cos x, b = \sin x$ afterwards.

Lastly, there is a separate command to make the sine and cosine look nice within a math environment (between dollar signs \$ \$). So instead of writing `sin x` or `sin(x)`, which gives $sin x$ or $sin(x)$ respectively, you write `\sin x` or `\sin (x)`, which renders like this: $\sin x$, $\sin (x)$. Similarily, you can write `\cos x` to get $\cos x$, and there are a lot more trigonometric functions like this (`\tan x, \arcsin y, \cosh z`), not to mention other common mathematical terms, like logarithms (`\ln` and `\log`), max and min and similar functions (`\max, \min, \sup, \inf`) and so on. If you want to make your own (if what you want doesn't exist already) you use the following command: `\operatorname{Func}x`. It renders like this: $\operatorname{Func} x$.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I see I have made a few misprints here... I am very new to the concept of this type of algebra and hoping my logic is correct here. I should be using theta and not x for this question. I will make these changes.

Answer (score 1):

${(\cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta})^4}\to$

${(c+is)^4}\to$  (for brevity)

$\begin{matrix}
1&4&6&4&1\\
c^4&c^3&c^2&c&1\\
1&is&-s^2&-is^3&s^4\\
\hline
c^4&4ic^3s&-6c^2s^2&-4ics^3&s^4
\end{matrix}$

The terms pertaining to $\cos(4\theta)$  are the real ones; the imaginaries, after dispensing with $i$, pertain to $\sin(4\theta)$ .

So, $\cos(4\theta)=\cos^4\theta-6\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+\sin^4\theta$ .
And, taking advantage of the fundamental relation between sine and cosine, $\cos(4\theta)=8\cos^4-8\cos^2+1=8\sin^4\theta-8\sin^2\theta+1$